# Matching files with sftp.listdir

Tags: python

Apologies in advance as Im a complete noob with python.

Im writing a program that needs to do the following:
Connects into sftp and compares a match of the files in the sftp directory with a list of files that Im passing into an argument.  Im passing the list of files in FILE.

So If I do

```
FILES=sftp.listdir('/path/')
for F in FILE:
    if F not in FILES:
        do something
```

Im having difficulty matching the 2 because the

FILE's naming convention is `XXX_NNNNNN_YYYYMMDD_.1.txt`

while the

FILES naming convention is `XXX_NNNNN_YYYYMMDD_1.txt.ts<NNNNNNNNNN>.txt`
The `<NNNNNNNNNN>` is the POSIX time from the remote server

Comment: Aside: all-caps variable names (as opposed to constant names) are contrary to PEP-8. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for style conventions applicable to Python code.

Comment: ...also, when you say "list of files [...] passing into an argument" -- how are you passing a *list* into a single argument? Is it actually an argument list? Is it a glob-style / fnmatch expression? Is it space-separated or otherwise delimited?

Comment: ...anyhow, what's your goal? To match any file prefixed by an argument you were given, with any suffix matching `[.]ts[0-9]+[.]txt`?

Comment: Yes list of files comma delimited. i.e., FILE = args.file.split(',')  Yes, the goal is what you stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
files = sftp.listdir("/path/")
truncatedFilenames = set()
for fn in files:
    parts = fn.split(".")
    ## re-join just the first 2 parts
    truncatedFilenames.add(".".join(parts[:2]))
for f in otherFileList:
    if f not in truncatedFilenames:
        ## do something
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `rsplit()` make more sense, to avoid needing to rejoin contents to the left?

Comment: I have one more issue.  On the files that I am looking for on the ftp if its good the extension will be .fileaccept if its bad it will be .filereject.  I need it to say ACCEPTED OR REJECTED based on the extension.

Comment: Or just look for the files with the .fileaccept extension.